# Could Konrad Curze see beyond his own death?

Tags: warhammer-40k, horus-heresy

Konrad Curze the Night Haunter is able to see the future. At various points during the horus heresy it is shown that he can see the fates or others including how and when they will die and most famously the exact moment he would die and how it would occur. He also predicted the turn of Horus telling Fulgrim about it.

Where Curze’s abilities limited only to events during his own lifetime? Was he able to see beyond his own death or did that act as a breakpoint first his visions of the future?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Having now read Konrad Curze the Primarch book it is clear that there is at least one person who’s future he sees long beyond his death. Soul Hunter, he sees that he will kill M’Shen for a noble reason, he also sees what fate has in store for him throughout his life. As we know Soul Hunter dies many 10,s of thousands of years after Curze this shows that he can see well beyond his own death. His sight was just more clouded and focussed for most people on the events of the heresy and his own assassination.